# WT32-ETH01 BLE+ETH issue

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ethernet, freertos, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

Both Ethernet and BLE works fine separately but when I compile them together, my board (WT32-ETH01) keep getting reset.

After some trial and error, I found out that `ETH.begin()` is having conflict with `BLEDevice::init()`. So I dig into the code and found out `BLEDevice::init()` function is using vTaskDelay which means that freeRTOS is implemented on it. Whereas `ETH.begin()` function is using delay(); Maybe this could be the reason?

Anyone have experience on how to overcome this? example:

`

```
#include <ETH.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLE2902.h>

/* 
   * ETH_CLOCK_GPIO0_IN   - default: external clock from crystal oscillator
   * ETH_CLOCK_GPIO0_OUT  - 50MHz clock from internal APLL output on GPIO0 - possibly an inverter is needed for LAN8720
   * ETH_CLOCK_GPIO16_OUT - 50MHz clock from internal APLL output on GPIO16 - possibly an inverter is needed for LAN8720
   * ETH_CLOCK_GPIO17_OUT - 50MHz clock from internal APLL inverted output on GPIO17 - tested with LAN8720
*/
#define ETH_CLK_MODE    ETH_CLOCK_GPIO17_OUT

// Pin# of the enable signal for the external crystal oscillator (-1 to disable for internal APLL source)
#define ETH_POWER_PIN   16  // GPIO16, HS1_DATA4, U2RXD, EMAC_CLK_OUT

// Type of the Ethernet PHY (LAN8720 or TLK110)
#define ETH_TYPE        ETH_PHY_LAN8720

// I²C-address of Ethernet PHY (0 or 1 for LAN8720, 31 for TLK110)
#define ETH_ADDR        1

// Pin# of the I²C clock signal for the Ethernet PHY
#define ETH_MDC_PIN     23  // GPIO23, VSPID, HS1_STROBE

// Pin# of the I²C IO signal for the Ethernet PHY
#define ETH_MDIO_PIN    18  // GPIO18, VSPICLK, HS1_DATA7

void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(115200);

   // Create and name the BLE Device
   BLEDevice::init("DEVICE_NAME");
   
   Serial.println("DEBUG_1"); // DEBUG
   
   ETH.begin(ETH_ADDR, ETH_POWER_PIN, ETH_MDC_PIN, ETH_MDIO_PIN, ETH_TYPE, ETH_CLK_MODE);

   Serial.println("DEBUG_2"); // DEBUG
}
void loop()
{}
```

`

This is the most simplified way to reproduce the issue. I know there is still a lot in between. Just to avoid any further confusion and straight to the point, I am trying my best to simplify it. Try commenting out the ETH.begin(), it will work.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add a [mre]? Maybe something in the way you initialize both libraries can be changed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for those who met the same issue, here is the solution:
Open the "tools" on top of our Arduino IDE
Tools > Partition Scheme > Huge APP.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I found out that memory overflow might occurs within two basic function `tcpipInit()` within `ETH.begin()` and `esp_bluedroid_init()` within `BLEDevice::init()`

The tcpipInit() function contains `_start_network_event_task()` functions, there is one line of code that might be the root cause:

`xTaskCreateUniversal(_arduino_event_task, "arduino_events", 4096, NULL, ESP_TASKD_EVENT_PRIO - 1, &_arduino_event_task_handle, ARDUINO_EVENT_RUNNING_CORE);`

On the other hand, there is a line of code`xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(btc_task, "Btc_task", BTC_TASK_STACK_SIZE, NULL, BTC_TASK_PRIO, &xBtcTaskHandle, 0);` which can be found within `btc_init()` under `esp_bluedroid_init()`

The BTC_TASK_STACK_SIZE can be found defined as 2048 according to esp-idf-2.0 ‎ tools/unit-test-app/sdkconfig

As we can see above, they both used around 6144 of total stack size. Just curious if they really need that much stack size?